# Monitor all network traffic going in and out a specific computer/ip address

Tags: monitoring, vpn

I'm looking for a tool under windows or mac that allows me to monitor (possibly in a simple way) the traffic going in and out of a computer of my network.

Long story short the residence where I live allows themselves to monitor the internet connection (and doesn't allow us to switch to another provider).

This annoys me on a personal level (I don't like the possibility of people checkin what I do without my knowledge as a general rule regardless of what I do) but also on a professional level (I sometimes work form home).

I'm using/trying out vpn providers (JAP, VyperVPN...) to avoid all this. it works fine with the http connections (if I run iptraces I end up in germany or US or UK ...) but I'm not sure for other applications such as online games, instant messaging softwares that use different ports.

So my question is how can I make sure that my internet traffic is using my vpn connection or not ?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark would do that for you on Windows and linux (Not sure about Mac). It uses WinPCap library and wraps in a nice UI for you to monitor the packets that you are interested. It allows you to listen to specific or all interfaces , so you can make sure your packets are going via the right interface

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but for the record: Wireshark can run on modern versions of Mac OS as well.  DMG installation images are available right on their download page: http://www.wireshark.org/download.html
However, I've had some little quirks using it, such as the dock icon appearing as "X11" (cosmetic only) and some network interfaces not being available to capture traffic (this can be caused by incorrect permissions too).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want them monitoring your internet usage, a vpn is a good solution, a vpn will encrypt all of your net traffic between your computer and the vpn gateway -- essentially you'd be surfing the web via a proxy and your landlords wouldnt be able to determine what you are doing.

assuming you are using a real vpn, and not just a browser based proxy solution, then the vpn should encrypt and tunnel all of your network traffic, this includes anything coming out of any port on your computer, not just http traffic.

when you install a vpn on your computer, the vpn creates a fake network device, and all of the vpn traffic gets tunneled to the vpn gateway. you can verify this by looking at your computer's routing tables. there are some vpns which allow for split traffic (split tunneling), e.g. traffic to certain domains gets tunneled through the vpn and others goes in the clear, but this is the rarity, most vpns will tunnel all of your traffic, which seems to be what you are looking for.

just make sure that your vpn uses an encryption protocol, there are some that don't -- this would defeat the whole purpose of your vpn.

Comment: Jason is not looking for VPN details. He needs a way to determine if the packets are going down the VPN interface.

Comment: yes, perhaps there is a bit of extraneous information there, but i did say he could verify this by looking at his computers routing tables. furthermore, mentioning split tunneling as well as the encryption protocol used is a directly relevant consideration.

Comment: +1 Because why on earth would somebody downvote such a clear, comprehensive, and on-topic answer?